# Is there a way I can keep my plant off of my desk?

Tags: indoors

I bought a [pothos plant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipremnum_aureum) for my work desk. Right now it's a standard a 5 inch diameter pot. I'd like to raise the plant up some, above the surface of the desk, maybe 12 to 24 inches.

I don't want to use an obtrusive stand (one with lots of decorations decoration), I'm looking for something that has a small footprint, so that it takes up as little desk space as possible.

Are there any products or homemade solutions that would accomplish this?

Comment: You could probably find something if you look hard enough, but most plant stands are meant to be decorative. Plus I'd worry about something that tall on a desk - could easily be knocked over at that height.

Comment: I would also be okay with other "solutions" one can think of that frees up desktop space, not necessarily product-based.

Comment: My first thought, when I saw the title in Hot Network Questions, was "Why is your plant getting on your desk? *How* is your plant getting on your desk??"

Comment: Do you have a desktop computer on your desk?
Is it oriented vertically?
Would it support your plant?

Comment: Given the growth habits of pothos, no matter whether you put it--on a stand or not--you're sooner or later going to have to deal with a heck of a lot of foliage on or around your desk. Perhaps you might consider putting it in a window instead, if you have one (preferably north-facing).

Comment: What is your light situation?  How long has this plant been in this 5" pot?  As long as you have windows nearby this plant will thrive and grow long (not wide).  I'd replant in a larger pot with sterile potting soil, feed it Osmocote 14-14-14 twice a year, water it in the bathroom in a sink until it stops draining (wash the leaves of dust) and put it back in a plant stand with a plastic drip pan beneath.  Once it gets longer, loop it through wire hoops installed in your ceiling brackets. Bring a big bucket in with water and submerge pot until air bubbles stop.  Allow to drain and replace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the solution I went with. A local plastic company custom-made this clear acrylic "display riser" for me. It's 12 inches high with an 8 inch square base. Cost about $20.

[image: Please excuse the shaky camera.]

These display risers are the things you usually see in stores that raise merchandise off of a table (think a jewelry department, for example).

One great advantage of this shape is the available space below the stand. The clear acrylic also doesn't visually darken my desk space like a dark metal stand would.

Answer (score 5):

I'd use a floor standing adjustable height wrought iron sheperd's hook, like this one

http://www.save-on-crafts.com/hookadjustable.html

You can set it up next to your desk, it completely frees up your desk space, has no decoration, and is adjustable as your plant grows.

This is the product description

> Great for hanging lanterns, wreaths, or planters, the adjustable black
>   iron shepherds hook is made of sturdy wrought iron. The height is
>   adjustable, from 34" to 55" and it stands on a 10" wide base. The hook
>   holds 40 lbs. Made from tough materials, the hook it is weather
>   resistant.

[image]

Comment: Nice idea. Do you know how many pounds maximum this will take, before tipping over?

Comment: According to the website up to 40 lbs.  I'll add that description to my answer.

Comment: That's plenty, for any reasonable pothos plant.

Comment: Yes, it may not be tall enough depending on what the OP wants, at maximum height of 55" it should be well over two feet over the desk surface, but then the plant must hang below that.

Comment: This is a nice outside-the-box solution; certainly doesn't take up any desk space.

Answer (score 4):

At an 18-24" height, you will expect some stands to be somewhat wider at the base. The least obtrusive material you can use is probably going to be steel, as it can be sufficiently strong without taking up much space. So a simple style like one of these might be useful:

[image][image]

If you want wood, expect a more bulky stand, but possibly with a shelf which could be useful.

[image][image]

There are so many pot stands, they should be easy to find. there is some worry if you're clumsy and tend to knock stuff over, because most of the weight will be on top, unless the pothos is very heavy with long vines.

Answer (score 3):

Hang it from the ceiling, or a bracket mounted to the wall or your partition. If the space is available, get an even larger stand for the floor. Also, be wary of using the desk space below a bucket of dirt you pour water into often.